# Ramda pick for fp-ts options / maybe

Tags: ramda.js, fp-ts, monocle-ts

Using [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#frompredicate). I have an option of an array

```
const arrayofKeys: Option<Array<K>>,
```

and an option of a record

```
const record: Option<Record<K,V>>
```

I want to pick the Vs of the Record where Ks intersect with the Array and stick the result in an Option.

In ramda: `R.pick(arrayOfKeys, record)`

How do i solve this with fp-ts or other packages within the fp-ts ecosystem?

Answer (score 4):

I'd personally avoid Ramda et al as in my experience they're not very well typed. Here's a pure fp-ts approach (`Str.fromNumber` is from fp-ts-std, trivially replaced):

```ts
declare const arrayOfKeyNums: Option<Array<number>>
const arrayOfKeys = pipe(arrayOfKeyNums, O.map(A.map(Str.fromNumber)))
declare const record: Option<Record<string, number>>

const keyIntersectedVals: O.Option<Array<number>> = pipe(
  sequenceT(O.Apply)(arrayOfKeys, record),
  O.map(([ks, rec]) =>
    pipe(
      rec,
      R.foldMapWithIndex(Str.Ord)(A.getMonoid<number>())((k, v) =>
        A.elem(Str.Eq)(k)(ks) ? [v] : [],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

It's a bit verbose owing to the need to pass typeclass instances around. On the plus side, the use of typeclass instances means that this can be trivially updated to support any value type, including non-primitive types with any given `Eq`.

Here's what the body might instead look like in Haskell for comparison, where typeclass instances don't need to be passed around:

```hs
keyIntersectedVals :: Maybe [Int]
keyIntersectedVals = uncurry (M.foldMapWithKey . intersectedToList) <$> sequenceT (mkeys, mmap)
  where intersectedToList ks k v
          | k `elem` ks = [v]
          | otherwise   = []
```

For example, given keys `O.some(["a", "c"])` and a record `O.some({ a: 123, b: 456, c: 789 })`, we get `O.some([123, 789])`.

Answer (score 3):

Ramda's [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) *lifts* a function on some values to work on a *container* of those values. So `lift (pick)` will likely do what you want, so long as fp-ts's `Option` supports the [FantasyLand Apply](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply) specification.

```js
const {of} = folktale.maybe
const {lift, pick} = R

const keys = of (['k', 'e', 'y', 's'])  // Maybe (['k', 'e', 'y', 's'])
const record = of ({s: 1, k: 2, y: 3, b: 4, l: 5, u: 6, e: 7}) // Maybe ({s: 1, k: 2, ...})

console .log (lift (pick) (keys, record) .toString())
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/folktale/2.0.0/folktale.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for `traverseArray`, an optimized version of `traverse`. You can also use "Do notation" and `apS` to get a really clean, monadic pipeline. If any of these operations return a `None`, the entire flow will terminate early (this is a good!).

Also, `lookup` is a very handy function similar to `get` from Ramda/Lodash, but it returns an Option. Both the Record and Array modules export a version of this function.

```js
declare const arrayofKeys: O.Option<Array<string>>
declare const record: O.Option<Record<string, number>>

export const result: O.Option<ReadonlyArray<number>> = pipe(
  O.Do,
  O.apS('keys', arrayofKeys),
  O.apS('rec', record),
  O.chain(({ keys, rec }) =>
    pipe(
      keys,
      O.traverseArray(key => pipe(rec, R.lookup(key)))
    )
  )
)
```

Functions used:

1. https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#do
2. https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#aps
3. https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#chain
4. https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#traversearray
5. https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Record.ts.html#lookup